# Python, Kivy: Al actualizar la variable "pressed" (ListPtoperty) no se ejecuta el método de evento "on_pressed()"

Tags: python, kivy

Asignando nuevo valor a un ListProperty su método de evento on_<prop_name>() sólo se ejecuta una vez.

Se trata de un ejemplo de la documentación oficial:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event

Se dice: "We define the ***pressed*** Property of type ListProperty, giving it a default value of [0, 0]. From this point forward, the ***on_pressed*** event will be called whenever the value of this property is changed." cuya traducción es "Definimos la Propiedad ***pressed*** de tipo ListProperty, dándole un valor por defecto de [0, 0]. A partir de este momento, se llamará al evento ***on_pressed*** cada vez que se cambie el valor de esta propiedad."

Si modifico la línea 26 que originalmente está así:
**self.pressed = touch.pos**

de esta forma:
**self.pressed = [250, 250]**

igualmente estoy modificando el valor del ListProperty ***pressed***, pero ya no se vuelve a capturar el evento más veces: los siguientes clics no son capturados y no vuelve a ejecutarse el método ***on_pressed()***. Mi pregunta es **¿Por qué? (pregunta 1ª)**.

Leyendo la documentación oficial he creido entender que si tenemos una variable de clase de uno de los tipos ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, etc. cada vez que su valor sea actualizado dentro de la propia clase se ejecutará automáticamente el evento denominado de la misma forma que la variable con el prefijo "on_". **¿Es esto correcto? (pregunta 2ª)**.

Muchas gracias por las explicaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me respondo a mí mismo:

## Pregunta 1

¿Por qué modificando la línea 26 del código original el evento ***on_pressed()*** sólo se ejecuta una vez?

Respuesta: Porque la línea la modifico quedando así:
***self.pressed = [250, 250]***

y:

1. **self.pressed** siempre recibirá el mismo valor, la lista [250, 250], y por tanto el cambio de valor sólo ocurre una vez ya que las demás veces recibe el mismo valor.
2. Según la documentación oficial, el método de evento asociado a una variable de cualquiera de los tipos xProperty sólo será llamado a ejecutar cuando se produzca un cambio de valor, y como dije en el punto superior, esto sólo ocurre una vez. Leer la primera nota de la documentación oficial bajo el subtítulo "*[Dispatching a Property event](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event)*"

Si en lugar de esa única línea de código asignando siempre el mismo valor ponemos estas que lo van alternando, siempre se ejecutará el método de evento ***on_pressed()***:

> ```
>         if self.pressed == [250.0, 250.0]:
>             self.pressed = [100.0, 100.0]
>         else:
>             self.pressed = [250.0, 250.0]
> ```

## Pregunta 2

Respuesta: **Sí, siempre que se produzca un cambio de valor, o sea, que reciba un valor distinto al que ya tiene.**